# Trigger onChange event for Select Box(Jquery Chosen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on onChange event of Jquery Chosen Select. I have little difficulty in the behavior of onChange event. Followings are the detail:
SelectBox:

```js
$("#SelectBox").change(function() {
  $("#SelectBox").val('A').trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectBox">
  <option selected>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

in above case user will be able to see the original text (A), but again he selects B then the onchange event will not fire .

So How to call the onchange event in above scenario.

Comment: What your code does is set the value to A whenever the user selects something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask user Yes and No which you can do by either using standard JavaScript Confirm Box it will show OK or Cancel but you can replace it with JQuery plugins which will say exact Yes or NO. To give a idea i have put default confirm box here. Hope this helps

```js
$("#SelectBox").change(function ()
    {
      // when user selects B then
     // it will show Yes/No Type Alert using sweet alert
     var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
  $("#SelectBox").val('B').trigger("liszt:updated");
} else {
    $("#SelectBox").val('A').trigger("liszt:updated");
   
}
    // if user press **YES** then it will set the select box text as B
    // if user press **NO** then it will again set the old value (A) to the select box. 


//following code will set the old value.
        

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectBox">
    <option selected>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    </select>
```